# parse.com swift: How to use afterSave, beforeDelete, afterDelete in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can I use afterSave, beforeDelete, afterDelete methods from parse.com (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave) in Swift? In the docs I don't get a Swift example.

As I am having data with pointers, it would be nice to use the afterSave increment for a counter as well as to check for related data before deleting it.

Has anyone used this before and could show me how that could look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The afterSave, beforeSave, and afterDelete methods are written in JavaScript and run on Parse.com as CloudCode functions.

There is no Swift (or Objective-C) versions, just JavaScript that gets called automatically when an object is saved or deleted.

Start with their [getting started guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started) to set up your environment and write some code.